# Removing duplicates from SQL query in One to many relationship

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have a table relationship as following:

Table 1 -> Table 2 (one to many relationship in DB)

If I do the following query on table 1:

```
select *
from table1 as t1
where t1.id = 1
```

I will get only one record for a specific record from that table, but if I do join on the table 2 as following:

```
    select *
    from table1 as t1
    join table2 as t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
    where t1.id=1
```

This time I will get multiple records if I have ID from table 1 inserted multiple times in table 2. The question is now, is there any way to show just 1 record after doing this join in query, in one to many relationship??

Can someone help me out with this?? Thanks!

I have used koppinjo's way and the query now looks as following:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY PC.SubCategoryID 
                                     ORDER BY PC.[SubCategoryID] ) AS [Row]
                   ,sc.*
                   ,pc.MeasurementQuantity
                   ,pc.Price
                   ,pc.ProductCategoryID
                   ,pc.ProductID
                   ,p.Dimensions
                   ,p.FileName
                   ,p.ProductDescription
                   ,p.ProductName
                   ,mu.Unit
          FROM      SubCategory AS sc
                    JOIN ProductsCategories AS pc ON sc.SubCategoryID = pc.SubCategoryID
                    JOIN Products AS p ON p.ProductID = pc.ProductID
                    JOIN MeasurementUnits AS mu 
                          ON mu.MeasurementUnitID = p.MeasurementUnitID
          WHERE     pc.SubCategoryID = 1
        ) AS t
WHERE   t.[Row] = 1
```

The problem is now, the query returns only 1 result. But what if there are two products that are under the same category ??

P.S. I forgot to mention that the actual DB schema for this query is:

Products -> ProductsCategories <- Categories

So lets say that 2 products are under two categories, i need to get both of the products, but without duplicates. Koppinjo's way returns only 1 result...

Comment: You get multiple records since there are multiple records that fits your criterion. How will sql serevr know what values to get from table2? you need to provide a condition to filter the rows in table2 that has the same id  as t1.id.

Comment: Like Zohar Peled said, you need to tell wich rows in table 2 you want to see. For example, do you want to see the first row in table 2? Or the biggest value? You need to provide a condition to filter the rows, or do a group by or something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a window function like ROW_NUMBER().  For instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t2.[primary/unique key]) AS [row]
         ,t1.*
      FROM table1 t1
          JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
      WHERE t1.id = 1
     ) t
WHERE t.[row] = 1
```

Something like this should get you pointed in the right direction.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you please view my updated question. I have used your way but its not 100% working, and I'm not sure why...

Comment: Try changing the ORDER BY column (in the PARTITION BY part of the query) to something other than PC.[SubCategoryID].  Usually you'd want to order by something like a created date or an orderId - something that has a natural cardinality.

Comment: I've changed it, but still returns 1 result only... The problem is , what if two different products are under the same sub category? This query returns only one product at a time, but how to display both of them (if there are two products under the same category). It's many to many relationship...

Comment: Could it be due to this in your code: "where pc.SubCategoryID=1"?  Without having a good grasp on your data, it's hard for me to advise on how to structure the ROW_NUMBER() function.  The way it is above, you're splitting the data into groups by SubCategoryId, then ranking them and returning the top 1, which is why you're only getting one result.  Probably need to tweak something in the ROW_NUMBER() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct and don't show any columns from table2. Something like:

```
select distinct t1.*
from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id=1
```